# Perl serialize nested reference to string

Tags: perl

I'm looking for a solution for using complex keys (arbitrary references) as hash keys, except that they perform deep comparison on the keys as opposed to reference comparison.

I am looking for a function preferably in a core module that serializes arbitrary references (possibly excluding subroutine and typeglob references) to strings in such a way that they can be reconstituted later.

```
 my @complex_key = qw[key1 key2];
 my %hash;
 $hash{serialize([@complex_key])} = 'value';

  deserialize((keys %hash)[0]);
   # should deeply equal [@complex_key]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to serialize all that data just to have a (potentially enormous) hash key.  Instead, take the checksum of the data structure and use that for a key.  Store the original key as part of the value.

Here's an example using [perl5i to do the deep checksum](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl5i/lib/perl5i/Meta.pod#checksum).

```
use perl5i::2;
$hash{@stuff->mo->checksum} = {
    key   => \@stuff,
    value => 'value'
};

my $value = $hash{@stuff->mo->checksum}{value};
my $key   = $hash{@stuff->mo->checksum}{key};
```

You can wrap this in a little class to make it more convenient.

```
sub get {
    my $self = shift;
    my $key  = shift;

    return $self->{$key->mo->checksum}{value};
}

sub set {
    my $self = shift;
    my($key, $val) = @_;

    $self->{$key->mo->checksum} = $val;

    return;
}

sub each {
    my $self = shift;
    my $code = shift;

    my $val;
    while( (undef, $val) = each %$self ) {
        $code->($val->{key}, $val->{value});
    }

    return;
}

$obj->set(\@stuff, "value");
my $value = $obj->get(\@stuff);

$obj->each( func($key, $val) {
    say "$key -> $val\n";
}
```

Comment: The Perl5i module is really cool, but I'm not sure I need an entire meta object extension to construct a deep checksum of an arbitrary value. I checked the implementation of `checksum` and it uses `Data::Dumper` to get a string representation of arbitrary values and to sort keys in hashes.

What is the advantage of that approach over setting `$Storable::canonical = 1`, and then hashing the resulting serialization of the data structure?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet perl5i brings all sorts of other value to your fingertips, and `$foo->mo->checksum` is already implemented and tested. But any serialization + checksum technique will work. The point is the technique, not the implementation.